# Summing numbers in a list in Python with a specific condition

Tags: python, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to sum linearly the numbers in this list, BUT, only if the next int type number is different from the before:

```
['2', '4.384508781', '2', '1.38586366', '2', '25.4309252', '1', '9.969634146', '1', '10.3821918', '2', '70.02500521', '1', '12.21172958', '1', '13.53189471', '1']
```

For example, for the first I want to add 2+4.384508781.
But, in the second time, I want to add only the 1.38586366 to the already (2+4.384508781) since the int is the same as before. And, if it is not, to add the int.

**EDIT1:**

I simplifed it. I divided the numbers in 2 lists, like this:

```
['2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1]    
['4.384508781', '1.38586366', '25.4309252', '9.969634146', '10.3821918', '70.02500521', '12.21172958', '13.53189471', '6.166945117', '16.28642897']
```

What I want to do is, on the first iteration, sum the first 2 and 4.384508781.
But, in the second, since the second number in the first list is the same as before ( 2 = 2 ) I want do add only the 1.38586366. This is put on a mathematic formula, but I just want to know how can I put a condition so that it doesn't sum the INT number in the first list if it is the same as the one previous.

Comment: An example output would go a long way, maybe with the full details of the calculation, and maybe with simpler numbers.

Comment: Please show your code so far and identify the specific parts where you are stuck.

Comment: What about the 2 between 1.38586366 and 25.4309252?

Comment: Ok, check the edited answer please :)  (and sorry for not knowing how to properly format yet!)

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve/solve?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic, naive, FORTRAN like solution with your first data type:

```
int_and_floats = ['2', '4.384508781', '2', '1.38586366', '2', '25.4309252', '1', '9.969634146', '1', '10.3821918', '2', '70.02500521', '1', '12.21172958', '1', '13.53189471', '1', '6.166945117', '1', '16.28642897']

last_int = None
n = len(int_and_floats)
total = 0

for i in range(0, n, 2):
    a, b = int(int_and_floats[i]), float(int_and_floats[i + 1])
    total += b
    if a != last_int:
        total += a
    last_int = a

print(total)
# 175.775127174
```

With your second data format, you could just use `groupby` to chunk the ints together before summing them:

```
from itertools import groupby
ints = ['2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1']
floats = ['4.384508781', '1.38586366', '25.4309252', '9.969634146', '10.3821918',
          '70.02500521', '12.21172958', '13.53189471', '6.166945117', '16.28642897']

print(sum(map(float, floats)) + sum(int(i) for i, _ in groupby(ints)))
```

And with numbers instead of strings, your code could be:

```
from itertools import groupby
ints = [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
floats = [4.384508781, 1.38586366, 25.4309252, 9.969634146, 10.3821918, 70.02500521, 12.21172958, 13.53189471, 6.166945117, 16.28642897]
print(sum(floats) + sum(i for i, _ in groupby(ints)))
# 175.775127174
```

Comment: dang it, just before me :P

Comment: That works and thanks, but I was looking for a more simple version without the groupby function ( we didnt use it in classes, and this is for a mini project in school, and I will have to defend it with my knowledge). But didn't knew you could do it like that, thanks!

Comment: @FredPinho: So take the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['2', '4.384508781', '2', '1.38586366', '2', '25.4309252', '1', 
     '9.969634146', '1', '10.3821918', '2', '70.02500521', '1', 
     '12.21172958', '1', '13.53189471', '1']

prev = 0
sm = 0
for each in a:
    if each.isdigit() and int(each)!=prev:
        sm += int(each)
        prev = int(each)
    elif '.' in each:
        sm += float(each)
print(sm)
```

should do the trick

Comment: How would it be if it was 2 lists like in the edited answer? Thanks and sorry for bothering!

Answer (score 0):

Consider such solution for your first list:

```
ls = ['2', '25.1','2', '25.2','2','25.3']
class Counter():count = 1

def summer(x,y):
    if Counter.count>1:
        one_before= ls[Counter.count-2]
        if y == one_before:
            Counter.count+=1
            return float(x)
    Counter.count+=1
    return float(x)+float(y)

summ = reduce(summer,ls)
print summ
```

it gives the sum of 77.6 which is 2+25.1+(skip)+25.2+(skip)+25.3